# "The Bonjour service could not be resolved."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bonjour

After updating to `6.3` whenever I launch `Xcode` I get this message.
Any idea how to get rid of this?

[image]

Edit: Why is this question on hold? Many people experience the very same issue..

**Problem resolved. For a solution, please refer to:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682940/1938719

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've encountered the same problem...

Comment: The same issue I have

Comment: Looks like someone found a resolution to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682939/after-upgrading-to-xcode-6-3-on-launch-i-now-get-the-error-the-bonjour-servic